# I can react on my own post in Teams

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-for-teams, reactions

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not, but I just noticed Teams has reactions, and of course, I immediately had to test.

[image: (Pardon the sloppy paint job.)]

I would have expected for this not to be possible, though I suppose there are situations where my own action can provoke a reaction. I don't see any icons to convey remorse or the pale cast of thought, though. Is this [statusbydesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/statusbydesign) or a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug)?

Comment: You can also like your own FB or Twitter post, react to your own Slack message... etc. there’s no reputation impact. Is there a reason to prevent it? I’m not sure if it’s intended or not but this might be an interesting thing to think about. :)

Comment: Sounds like bugs should be filed against Facebook, Twitter, and Slack. It makes negative sense to react to your own post.

Comment: @Catija: And your [own YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6PCZT2pg6A)... (upvote or downvote)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this is indeed working as intended. Our Teams team considered situations where a user may want to react to their own content - to encourage others to react, to give themselves a thumbs up, etc.